# Linux BLE Scanning after a CTRL+C

Tags: linux, bluez

I have a C program that works well the first time it runs (BLUEZ C API) but if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop it and then if I run it again it never finds any BLE device (scanning function). If I reboot linux it works again. My program is in a while(1) loop scanning and printing device info (including manufacturer data) and calls:

```
stop_hci_scan(current_hci_state);
error_check_and_exit(current_hci_state);
close_hci_device(current_hci_state);
```

are outside loop.

The program **must** survive to this event (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) because I am planning to put it into a linux service in order to be possible to restart it automatically if it hangs or something.

So, it seems that I need to perform some cleaning before launching program the second time (to avoid reboot), right?

But what?

Answer (score 1):

You can use (at the command line):

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 reset
```

I don't know the C equivalent...